# Display array contents in UITextView

Tags: uitextfield, nsarray

I am trying to display my array contents in a UITextView. This should be simple. The array echoes using NSlog

```
(
        (
        "Point 1",
        "Point 2",
        Point3
    )
)
```

using the following doesn't work as I know the array needs to be broken down.

```
cell.textField.text = arrayContents;
```

I am looking at how to cycle through the array and display the content in a `UITextField`? The array is stored in `arrayContents`

Comment: Do you want display array contents in single textfield or textfield in different cells?

Comment: ideally in a single textfield but on different lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with UITextField but it is possible in UITextView. Try this. If you used in textfield the output will be Point 1 Point 2 Point 3

```
textView.text = [YourArrayName componentsJoinedByString:@"\n "];
```

Comment: perfect. I actually meant UITextView.

Comment: @user2960468 thanks for accept. can you give upvote?

Comment: when I apply it to a uitextview, it shows the parenthesis. Is there away to get around that? textView.text = [columns componentsJoinedByString:@"\n "];